# What are good security tactics for sleeping in airports?

Tags: safety, tips-and-tricks, airports, security, sleeping

Sleeping in airports is something I've found myself doing more often than I ever expected, and while I have no issue with sleeping on the floor or chairs or whatever, sometimes I have valuable stuff, and if travelling alone or in a small group, or if in a dodgy small airport with no security (or worse, corrupt security), what tactics can you use to keep you and your valuables safe?

Comment: This probably applies just as well to train and bus stations, both of which I have spent more nights in than airports (-:

Comment: @hippietrail, Well at least you can lean against the window if you're on a vehicle...

Comment: @Pacerier: Not in the vehicles, just in the stations they arrive at and depart from.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

While I don't regularly sleep in the airports, I suggest you check out [these tips](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/tips.htm):

> Whether you are sleeping in the airport by yourself or with friends, **it is good to know where security is. Know where their office is and look for video cameras in the spot you decide to stay the night. They've probably seen many airport sleepers before you and they will direct you to a safe spot.**

If you suspect a problem with airport security, you may want to follow this tip and sleep in the car:

> Whether you are stuck in the airport overnight or choose to be there voluntarily, there may be a chance that you will be uncomfortable and unhappy with your surroundings in the terminal. **If you are travelling on a budget and do not want to fork out for one of the airport hotels, head over to the car rentals hall to find out the cost of a car rental and (assuming you can keep the car in the lot at no cost) sleep in the car**. The great part about this is that you can recline on padded seats and there will be no annoying security announcements or rattling luggage carts whipping past your head throughout the night. On the negative side, car horns and screeching tires may jolt you from your slumber. Sure the car rental staff may look into your car wondering if you've had a stroke and the bathroom may be an issue depending on the location of the nearest toilet, but hey, you're saving money here! Very important - remember to check the drop-off hours to ensure a staff member will be there when you "drop-off" the car before your flight the next morning! This is easier at larger airports.

Also, make sure to [check out the stories about the airport beforehand](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/index.htm) so you know if there are known problems before you face them.

Good luck!

Comment: Car? What car? :)

Comment: Also, did check out that link beforehand, but it doesn't have Astana Airport, unfortunately.  Have slept in 2 of the top 10 worst ones tho, hehe :)

Comment: @Mark: some airports have car rentals. But it's probably true this implies a better security as well :-)

Answer (score 20):

Use your suitcase/bag as your pillow, you'll know as soon as you miss it!
If you have more than one bag, put your hands through the bag handle or tie it to your hand or leg when you fall asleep.

Most importantly travel light, the lighter you travel, the safer you will be!

Comment: What about your wallets and passports?

Comment: @Pacerier: in this situation, I put my wallet and passport deep down inside the bag that I’m using as a pillow — so it would be pretty difficult to find them without without digging through the bag and hence waking me.  But I’ve only ever done this in fairly safe airports (in Western Europe and Australia, iirc) so I can’t speak for how effective it is in dodgier places.

Answer (score 20):

In airports in Christian countries, I also heartily recommend seeking out the chapel.  Its a nice, quiet place, where you can "meditate" in silence.  (Hey, I'm also an ordained priest, and while people like my sermons, don't think I haven't seen the occasional person "meditating" even during the songs!)  Its a easy place to find some shuteye, as long as you are respectful.  (Also, I would check the hours and make sure you won't be there for a service!) The beauty of this is that criminals tend to avoid chapels, mostly out of guilt, so you have a relatively safer place.

Along these lines, in Muslim countries, there are also ablution fountains near the prayer halls.  If you are really in need of a shower when you wake up, use the ablution fountain as a dip and pour.  Remember that Muslims pray (and wash) five times a day, so be discreet and look for non-prayer times.

Comment: stay well clear of any mosque area and certainly don't use the fountains unless you're a muslim. They consider that highly offensive and you could end up beaten up, arrested and charged with religious crimes, or worse.

Comment: I once tried to sleep in the "Prayer and Quiet Room" in some airport in Europe (I forget which one), and shortly after I laid down, a security officer entered and kicked me out of there.  He said only prayer was allowed, not sleeping.

Comment: @AffableGeek, What's a "[part time pastor](http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1445/affable-geek)" anyway?

Comment: @pacoverflow, Lol, is there a "no sleeping" sign there? In Singapore airport there are "no sleeping" signs around places that are not for sleeping... which suggests that everywhere else is for sleeping.

Comment: @jwenting based on what are you making these comments? Never have I seen anyone been beaten arrested or charged with a religious crime for using a bathroom. The water there is not sacred, and neither is the place.

Answer (score 8):

I find it useful to carry a light chain or a nylon strap, such as those found in backpacks (something difficult or time-consuming to cut through, enough to disturb your sleep). Wind it through your baggage limbs and then across a body part. This is quite useful for securing multiple pieces of luggage. 
Also, not directly related to the question - Carry a neck pillow, in case you don't have one already. You'll sleep like a baby!

Comment: How good are inflatable neck pillows? Are they worth the hassle of packing yet another item?

Comment: I have an inflatable neckpillow in my car, and I'd say they are good

Answer (score 7):

One of my biggest worries when sleeping in airports is whether my luggage is safe; everything else, I don't really care. If there's a 24-hour luggage storage or a locker facility I drop off my bags there and that helps incredibly in peace-of-mind in relaxing.

Now if you're the kind who passes out cold when sleeping then things are going to be difficult for you. However, if you find you can easily take [power naps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_nap) then you can take that at a cafe or a restaurant. They *will* throw you out if you stay too long but as long as you buy something you can safely catch some sleep for 30-60 minutes. Once you learn how to take power naps, you'll find it causes less fatigue as you can catch the restful cycles of sleep without sleeping in an uncomfortable position for too long.

Comment: any tips for catching power naps? I've never been easily able to fall asleep while sitting :(

Comment: The threshold for when exactly you fall into sleep beyond the point of no-return differs for people. For me, I find it's around 20-25 minutes. So when I started power-napping, I set multiple alarms around 20-25 minutes period to make sure I wake up. Do it enough times you can start doing it without multiple alarms - perhaps just one or even none. The main point is - you HAVE to wake up even if you feel a bit groggy, after a while the feeling goes away and you feel more refreshed. Break out a couple of power naps every 1-1.5 hours, you'll feel less groggy and your muscles with thank you for it

Comment: @MarkMayo, The best tip is you'd need to be tired. Then it all comes naturally. If you aren't tired then don't sleep, get a book or laptop or something.

Answer (score 5):

Hide your valuable items (if small) deep under your clothes, that way it will be hard to steal them from you (and hard to find).

You could also try to make a new friend (easy when you both are stuck at the airport) and keep an eye on each other. On the other hand your new "friend" might be a pickpocket, so use your brains.

Or if you have a lock with you, lock your bag to something fixed.

Comment: Your "new friend" might be a pickpocket.........

Comment: True, that's possible. I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is lockable bags.  I have a couple of [these](http://www.pacsafe.com/pacsafe-140l-backpack-bag-protector.html) for when we take train trips where the luggage security situation is much worse.  Beware that bigger is not always better--the bigger the bag the bigger the holes in the mesh that someone could use to worm something small out.

They're basically a wire mesh bag with a drawstring that you can loop around something substantial and then bring back to the bag and lock.  The biggest ones--which is what I linked--will hold bags as large as the airline carry-on limits.

While it's not perfect it's enough to defeat the thief intending to stealthily go through someone's bag or pick it up and pretend it's theirs.  I can't think of anything that could get through it that you're allowed on a plane.

Comment: worth saying what 'these' are - in case the link goes away or changes.

Comment: @MarkMayo I described the item in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

At the airports they usually have those plastic crates, either big ones to put your big bag when you checking or smaller ones that you put your things into at security check, or both.

You can grab some of these and put them upside down, side by side and form an improvised bed out of them. This serves two purposes:

1) You can put all your valuable things (if the crates are big enough) under the crates and it will be impossible to steal them while you lie on them.

2) It isolates you from the cold cold floor

Comment: Which crates are we talking about? Could you provide an image?